Does ABS contain natural rubber
Does ABS otherwise known as acrylonitrile butadiene styrene contain natural rubber also known as natural latex or is it synthetic latex?

It seems like you think all polymers are either natural or synthetic latex, which is simply not true. Probably closing the question as based on the false premise would be in order.

Pure ABS does not, but there might be ABS-isoprene blends.

Natural rubber is made of polymerized isoprene plus sulfur. ABS does not contain isoprene or its polymer.

As rightly pointed out by Maurice, regular ABS plastic itself doesn't contain natural rubber or natural latex. ABS is a completely synthetic material made from combining three different monomers: acrylonitrile, butadiene, and styrene.
However, there can exist ABS blends with natural rubber in them. Instead of using natural latex, however, processed natural rubber is used. This is usually done to create a stronger ABS blend with improved impact and tensile strength.(You do see these often in some car bumpers)

Natural rubber-based ABS - target polymer blends in accordance with the present disclosure can exhibit generally equivalent or increased impact and/or tensile strength compared to other non-natural or synthetic rubber-based ABS blends.

Source: https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2013141822A1/en

One might argue that a compound containing ABS plus natural rubber should not be called ABS.

@matt_black Fair enough. I decided to mention the blend, because I inferred that the person who asked the question might have a misunderstanding, or possibly might be talking about a blend. Regardless I did point out how ABS is completely different.
